# When do you have to use `/bin/sh -c "..."` in the CMD directive in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh

I have been studying `Dockerfile` implementations of several projects and I noticed that some of them start the application with:

```
CMD executable
```

while other do:

```
CMD /bin/sh -c "executable"
```

I have been trying both versions for each project, and don't really notice a difference.

Is there a difference? If so, when is which version preferred?

Comment: I think there is no deference docker use always `/bin/sh` as default so the first one is shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> - CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the    preferred form)
> - CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to    ENTRYPOINT)
> - CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)

...

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command
>   shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
>   $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or
>   execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"
>   ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the
>   case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment
>   variable expansion, not docker.

So

```
CMD executable
```

which uses the shell form is already implicitly invoking a shell. So there's no reason to explicit invoke one.